# GWT SeralizationStreamFactory reader issue

Tags: java, gwt, web-worker

I have a web application built in GWT which has the need to send and receive serialized data all client side. (I am using webworkers and need to exchange data between the main thread and the webworkers)

So far I am creating the serialized object (in this example I'm just sending ArrayLists of string objects, but I of course am really trying to sending arrays of serializable class objects)

There just doesn't seem to be much documentation on the proper use of this serialization / de-serialization process when it all happens client side.

But my writer function has the general shape of:

```
    public String streamResult(){
        SerializationStreamFactory factory = GWT.create(streamFactory.class);
        SerializationStreamWriter writer = factory.createStreamWriter();
        ArrayList<String> strlst = new ArrayList<>();
        strlst.add("First String");
        strlst.add("Second String");
        try {
           writer.writeObject(strlst);
        }  catch (Exception e) {
           printf("exception caught while serializing object");
        }
        return  writer.toString();
     }
```

And this properly creates a string object representing the ArrayList data

```
"7|0|6||788C596190777F280A9EF3D57029FB2C|java.util.ArrayList/4159755760|java.lang.String/2004016611|First String|Second String|1|2|3|2|4|5|4|6|"
```

But then when I go to deseralize the result set I get a error which somehow has to do with it trying to read integers in the result string.

```
 public void unStreamResult(String str){
        SerializationStreamFactory factory = GWT.create(streamFactory.class);
        try {
            SerializationStreamReader reader = factory.createStreamReader(str);
            stringArray.addAll((ArrayList<String>) reader.readObject());
        }  catch (Exception e){
            printf("exception caught while deseralizing object");
        }
    }
```

Where my streamFactory class created for my SeralizationStreamFactory is defined as:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("streamFactory")
public interface streamFactory extends RemoteService {
    ArrayList getMessage(ArrayList message);
    String getMessage(String message);
}
```

But then I get a **NumberFormatException** on a string of "" of some sort during the de-seralization process.

> Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>       at NumberFormatException_0.createError (Insights-0.js:13972)
>       at NumberFormatException_0.initializeBackingError (Insights-0.js:13995)
>       at NumberFormatException_0.Throwable_0 (Insights-0.js:13948)
>       at NumberFormatException_0.Exception_0 (Insights-0.js:14012)
>       at NumberFormatException_0.RuntimeException_0 (Insights-0.js:14022)
>       at NumberFormatException_0.IllegalArgumentException_0 (Insights-0.js:46625)
>       at new NumberFormatException_0 (Insights-0.js:46861)
>       at __parseAndValidateInt (Insights-0.js:22987)
>       at $prepareToRead (Insights-0.js:39707)
>       at $unStreamResult (Insights-0.js:9415)
>       at onMessageImpl (Insights-0.js:46204)
>       at Worker.this$static.onmessage (Insights-0.js:46198)

Comment: How are you deserializing that payload? Are you doing it on the server, or still on the client? I did this in a different way years ago in https://github.com/niloc132/webbit-gwt/, and am putting the finishing touches now on https://github.com/vertispan/gwt-rpc as a generator-free (and much more flexible) version of gwt-rpc, depending on what you need to get out of this. Can you also share the response payload, passed into `unStreamResult`, and how the remote end built it?

Comment: Its still on the client, as everything is on the client. This is the data passed from a webworker that has serialized the results of its operations and are passing them back into the main GWT thread.  The exact payload string being passed into unStreamResult is what is posted above. Your project above looks very interesting, and I will being looking through it, but what you see above is quite literally the meat of what I have implemented. I have tried the ClientSerializationStreamWriter (/Reader) as well...

Comment: @ColinAlworth, sorry I forgot to add your name to the previous comment, not sue if that is relevant for SO to notify you.. I've been going through your gwt-rpc implementation you posted above, is this actually going into GWT v3?

Comment: Yes I saw the message, and yes, this new gwt-rpc is designed to work in gwt3. I'll write up an answer for you in a bit, but short story: what you're doing won't work, at least the way you are doing it. One more question: why decode a client request on the client, if you want to be using this to send to the server over a websocket?

Comment: I don't know if I specified my use case above, but what i'm doing is having the webworkers do the heavy lifting of loading and pre-processing some large payloads from the actual server (back end is quite simple, written in PHP, and all it does is put SQL data into JSON form). I'm just looking for how to take the resulting arrays of post processed data (that would freeze the main UI thread for unacceptable amounts of time to process them front end) and pass from the web worker on to the main UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing GWT-RPC protocol is asymmetrical - one message format is used to go from the client to the server, and a different format is used to go from the server to the client. In all my work with RPC, I've never understood why this is the case, except maybe to make debugging mildly easier in that the two message formats are incompatible so you know at a glance what you are looking for?

In any case, that's why this doesn't work - your `unStreamResult` is expecting a differently formatted message, one which should start with `//OK` or `//EX` and then be followed by a JS array. That array will contain mostly numbers, but will also contain an array of strings.

In the draft update to the GWT-RPC repo, currently at https://github.com/vertispan/gwt-rpc (leave a message on this answer if that link gets stale, I'll update), we've changed the stream readers and writers to be fully symmetrical. This avoids the confusion you and others have faced, and makes it possible for the serialization format to be used independently, such as communicating with a Web Worker, or for some simple serialization to a Blob for use in IndexedDb or something (with the caveat that this format is *not* versioned, so data persisted across an update to your application might not work any more).

If you must have this format working before I complete that project, take a look at something like https://github.com/niloc132/webbit-gwt/blob/master/workers/src/main/java/com/colinalworth/gwt/worker/client/impl/StreamReader.java (and StreamWriter.java in the same package) - these are simply subtypes of `AbstractSerializationStreamReader` and `AbstractSerializationStreamWriter`, but carefully written to avoid any differences between client and reader. These are written to use ByteBuffers (which themselves wrap JS TypedArrays for better performance). There is a "modernized" version of this in the gwt-rpc project both for strings and for ByteBuffers, but they may not be fully compatible with old RPC. Using these comes with its extra work too: you must stop using `factory.createStreamWriter()` etc to build the reader and writer for you, and you must then access the `serializer` field from within the RemoteServiceProxy subclass (JSNI perhaps?).

---

But for your use case of WebSockets, you don't actually need a fully symmetrical wire format - you just need to send the payload over the wire to the server and have it decode it, then craft its own reply, and send back to the client. Once on the client, that response payload will correctly be read by your `unStreamResult` message.

And while I'm never one to discourage someone from reinventing the wheel, also consider using the gwt websocket project that I linked before, as it has already solved many of these issues. It isn't perfect of course, but it is getting a lot closer as we make it a first-class feature in the updated GWT-RPC module.

Comment: I wrote an answer anyway, hope it is flexible enough for you, leave a note if not. Please join us at https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt to help show us more about what you want out of GWT and GWT-RPC in the future!

Comment: Thank you very  much Colin, very informative, and explains a lot. The asymmetrical nature of the reader / writer is exactly the problem I'm encountering... I realize my use case is extremely unusual, hence why I have found so little information. Using web-workers instead of a traditional server back end is already unusual enough, but this is more of a educational project for myself trying to push the limits, while also building my company an internal dashboard that I don't have to worry about more than a couple dozen users experiences on and can troubleshoot issues personally.

Comment: Oh you are using web workers, I misread! Sorry about that. In that case, do consider either the "webbit-gwt" (name makes no sense, hasn't used webbit in years) or trying to work that basic idea into your own project. The worker code is moved to the updated gwt-rpc project too, though I haven't spent quite as much time on it yet. Part of the point of the updated "gwt-rpc" project is to actually separate serialization from actual Remote Procedure Calls, so that you can implement your own as needed.